# Scroll position lost in custom messenger app

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

working on some messenger functionality (think chat app like FB or WhatsApp). The database stuff is going great, and it displays, messages both sent and received, in a browser (I'm using Chrome). When a new message is sent, it shows up no problem.

Problem = when there are enough messages to trigger the div's vertical scrolling, all is fine — UNTIL I scroll up to see older messages. Then even when scrolling back down all the way the scroll "lock" is forever lost (or at least until the browser page is refreshed).

I did a fair bit of searching but I think my lack of understanding of the problem (and the right keywords to use) is bringing up no results. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Edit2: also uploaded a gif to this link to clarify:

https://gfycat.com/ifr/MasculineHeartfeltBirdofparadise

Edit: including some code. There are subcomponents that I won't include since it nests pretty deep, but basically it renders a chat window. The gif above will make it more clear. The overall component becomes scrollable on the Y axis when long enough thanks to the css included here as well.

```js
@graphql(gql`
  query ($mostRecent: Int, $userId: Int) {
    messages(mostRecent: $mostRecent, userId: $userId) {
      messageId
      userId
      messageText
      isAdmin
      createdAt
    }
  }
`, {
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      mostRecent: 25,
      userId: props.userId
    }
  })
})
export default class Messages extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    closeConversation: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    userId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }
  refetchMessages = () => {
    this.props.data.refetch()
  }
  loadMoreMessages = (userId) => {
    this.props.data.refetch({mostRecent: this.props.data.messages.length + 25, userId: this.props.userId})
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) return <Loading />

    return <div style={styles.messageInterface} key={this.props.userId}>
      <div style={{position: 'absolute', top: '0px', right: '0px',
        width: '100%', backgroundColor: 'white', height: '50px',
        borderBottom: '1px solid lightgray', zIndex: '1'}}
      >
        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <MessengerUserInfo userId={this.props.userId} />
        </div>
        <Button type="button" onClick={this.props.closeConversation} bsStyle="link"
          style={{fontSize: '21px', fontWeight: '700', textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000',
          position: 'absolute', right: '20px', top: '3px'}}
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true" style={{opacity: '0.2', ':hover': {opacity: '0.5'}}}X</span>
        </Button>
      </div>
      <MessageForm userId={this.props.userId} refetchMessages={this.refetchMessages}/>
      <div style={{...styles.messageInterface, padding: '20px', marginTop: '50px'}}>
          {this.props.data.messages.map((item)=> {
            return <Message key={item.messageId} messages={item}/>
          })}
          <div style={{alignSelf: 'center', paddingTop: '15px'}}><Button bsStyle='success' onClick={this.loadMoreMessages}>Load more</Button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

```css
let styles = {
  messageInterface: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    overflowX: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative'
  },
 }
```

Comment: Please provide some code examples that may have resulted in the issue. It helps people better answer your question. Read this post to better understand why there is a downvote: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 I apologize, thanks for that link. I'll include below what I consider the relevant code.